# how to use ping in expect script

Tags: scripting, expect

Need assistance while i want to ping server if got reply then proceed with script and if no reply go again to previous step where we fetch IP from hosts.txt

```
#Setting up Variables
set timeout 5                                                                                                                                
set fid [open ./hosts.txt r]
set contents [read -nonewline $fid]
close $fid

#Grabbing Password to be used in script further
stty -echo
send_user -- "Enter the Password: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
send_user "\n"
stty echo
set pass $expect_out(1,string)
foreach host [split $contents "\n"] {

    set timeout 5
    spawn ping $host
    expect  {
    "Reply" {puts "$host Is Up"}
    "Request" {puts "$host Is Down"}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Match the "%packet loss" in the summary of `ping`, like in the script below. As a side note, you mentioned that if the host is not reachable, control should be given back to the `foreach` loop, which would read the next host, but in your script, you actually try to do something upon failure, so I included a failure option as well.

```
# Procedure to be called for each
# reachable host
proc handleHost {host} {
    do things...
    expect eof
}

# To be called for unreachable hosts
proc hostFailed {host} {
    puts "$host is not reachable."
}

#Setting up Variables
set timeout 5
set fid [open ./hosts.txt r]
set contents [read -nonewline $fid]
close $fid

#Grabbing Password to be used in script further
stty -echo
send_user -- "Enter the Password: "
expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
send_user "\n"
stty echo
set pass $expect_out(1,string)
foreach host [split $contents "\n"] {

    set timeout 5
    spawn -noecho ping -q -w 1 -c1 $host
    expect {
        " 0% packet loss" { handleHost $host }
        eof               { hostFailed $host }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes if the host is not reachable i want the script to go and fetch the next IP from hosts file.Sometimes,we have interment connection so in you case if we get 50% reply.so wether script will consider it as failed?

Comment: edit 2 : i will run these scripts on cgywin @Lacek

Comment: In my example, `ping` sends only one probe (`-c1`), so it is either 100% success or 100% failure. If you want to have more options, you can include any number of patterns in the `expect` block. If a pattern matches, others will be ignored, so you should put the most exact rules first. On cygwin, the `ping` output is different if you use the `ping` program included in windows. In this case, you should match the `Received = 0` pattern to check for a failure, but if you install the `inetutils` package in cygwin, then the output will match the Linux version.